# MYSQL OR two values on one column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.

**Table 1: tA**

```
+----+--------------------+
| id | url                |
+----+--------------------+
| 1  | hxxp://www.aaa.com |
| 2  | hxxp://www.bbb.com |
+----+--------------------+
```

**Table 2: tB**

```
+----+-------+--------+----------+
|id  | tA_id | cat_id | cat_name |
+----+-------+--------+----------+
| 1  |   1   |    1   |  Mobile  |
| 2  |   1   |    2   |  Other   |
| 3  |   2   |    2   |  Other   |
+----+-------+--------+----------+
```

**Expected Output**

```
+----+-------+--------+----------+
| id | tA_id | cat_id | cat_name |
+----+-------+--------+----------+
| 1  |   1   |    1   |   Mobile |
| 3  |   2   |    2   |   Other  |
+----+-------+--------+----------+
```

**mysql code:**

```
select * 
from tA 
inner tB 
on tA.id = tB.tA_id 
where tB.cat_id = 1 
or tB.cat_id = 2 
Group By tA_id
```

**result from my mysql code:**

```
+----+-------+--------+----------+
| id | tA_id | cat_id | cat_name |
+----+-------+--------+----------+
| 1  |   1   |   2    |   Other  |
| 3  |   2   |   2    |   Other  |
+----+-------+--------+----------+
```

How do I do?

Comment: Try with group by cat_name.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your group by tA_id because it is grouping cat_name Mobile and Other together.

If you need to keep it use `ORDER BY tB.cat_id ASC` which i believe will show the cat_id 1 and 2 like you need it

Comment: But I have 300+ records in my database. If I use Group by cat_name. My results show 2 records.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in query... `JOIN` is missing...

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT * 
FROM tA 
INNER JOIN tB 
ON tA.id = tB.tA_id 
WHERE tB.cat_id = 1 
OR tB.cat_id = 2 
GROUP BY tA_id
```

This is fetching expected results

```
+----+---------------------+-----+--------+--------+----------+
| id |  url                |  id |  tA_id | cat_id | cat_name |
+----+---------------------+-----+--------+--------+----------+
| 1  | hxxp://www.aaa.com  |  1  |   1    |  1     |   mobile |
| 2  | hxxp://www.bbb.com  |  3  |   2    |  2     |   other  |
+----+---------------------+-----+--------+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
select * 
from tA 
inner join tB 
on tA.id = tB.tA_id 
where tB.cat_id = 1 
or tB.cat_id = 2 
group by tb.cat_name;
```

Hope it will help you.